# Как можно реализовать удаление строк, не имеющих ключевое слово?

Tags: python

Есть переменная, в этой переменной есть много строк, мне нужно оставить только те строки, в которых присутствует ключевое слово. В статьях, рассказывающих про работу со строками я такой информации не нашёл.

Comment: То есть как пример из `["a text", "text keyword", "keyword!", "notkeyword", "..."]` получить `["a text", "..."]`?

Comment: @IvanDidyk вот, скажем, есть "abc \n aeq \n qbc \n qeq", ключевое слово (символ) это a, получиться должно "abc \n aeq"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

алгоритм:

1. разбить строку на слова
2. проверить входит ли в слово искомая последовательность
3. сформировать список из таких слов
4. соединить слова из списка в строку

вариант 1:

```
text = "abc \n aeq \n qbc \n qeq"
letter = 'a'

res = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if letter in word)
print(res)
```

вариант 2:

```
res = ' '.join(filter(lambda word: letter in word, text.split()))
```

Comment: спасибо, всё работает, но ответ выводит как "abc aeq", возможно ли перед ними тоже вставить \n?

Comment: `'\n'.join(arr)` - просто соедините не через пробел, а через перенос строки :)

Comment: спасибо большое